# Android ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless look squared instead of circle

Tags: android, material-design, android-imagebutton

I am using Android support lib version 27.0.2. Tested on API 23. Android `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` used to be circle. But on my case it's squared I have no idea what's wrong.

```
`<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/vgSharePostHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/clickable_size_48">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSharePostCloseDialog"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clickable_size_32"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clickable_size_32"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/item_gap_l"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" << HERE 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/gray_text" /> ...
```

Result look like screenshot below:

[image]

Expected result should PIC 2

[PIC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liUrd.png)

Comment: its looks like its gone out of the bound . On which API level you have tested ?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Show your xml code

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`
on Manifest.xml made all `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` broken.

To fix the problem, I just remove the `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` from `application` tag.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give `layout_margin` in `ImageButton`

layout_margin should be greater than or equal to `(√2 * layout_width - layout_width)/2` so that `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` can be drawn fully.

if `clickable_size_32` is `32dp`, `layout_margin` will be `(√2*32 -32)/2 = 6.8`
then your `ImageView` should look like this -

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSharePostCloseDialog"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clickable_size_32"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clickable_size_32"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/gray_text" />
```

Comment: OP wants unbounded ripple.

Comment: Unfortunately `android:attr/selectableItemBackground` made my `ImageButton` squared. I want it's circle like on PIC 2 on question.

Comment: Is it possible other dependencies make squared ripple on `android:attr/selectableItemBackground`? because it was normal (circle ripple).

If it's possible, then how to track which 3rd party dependencies caused this problem?